# Aligning in CSS and Material UI in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How do I align one button to the left while the other two on the center?

Pls check codesandbox here
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-meadow-bd5che?file=/demo.js)

```
    <DialogActions sx={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Button>Left</Button>
      <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel center</Button>
      <Button onClick={handleClose}>Subscribe center</Button>
    </DialogActions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using Grid. Check out below codes.

```
<DialogActions
  sx={{
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplateColumns: "1fr repeat(2, auto) 1fr",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }}
>
  <Button sx={{ marginRight: "auto" }}>Left</Button>
  <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel center</Button>
  <Button onClick={handleClose}>Subscribe center</Button>
</DialogActions>
```